# separating constraints and UI elements (UIView, UIButton, UITextField, etc) declaration to separate swift file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, optimization, uiview

I have seen related articles but non of them addresses the similar problem. I would like to separate my view code e.g. `exampleView.swift` in a way that my UI components goes in a separate file, and my constraints that I apply over them goes into separate file.

**exampleView.swift**

```
import UIKit

class LoginController: UIViewController {

let inputContainerView: UIView = {
    var view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true

    return view
}()
let loginRegisterButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 80, g: 101, b: 161)
    button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(registerTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()
let nameTextField: UITextField = {
    var tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "Name"
    tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return tf
}()
let nameSeparatorView: UIView = {
    var view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 220, g: 220, b: 220 )
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return view
}()
let emailTextField: UITextField = {
    var tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "Email"
    tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return tf
}()
let emailSeparatorView: UIView = {
    var view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 220, g: 220, b: 220)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return view
}()
let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
    var tf = UITextField()
    tf.placeholder = "Password"
    tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tf.isSecureTextEntry = true

    return tf
}()
let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Dragon")
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 61, g: 91, b: 151)
    view.addSubview(inputContainerView)
    view.addSubview(loginRegisterButton)
    view.addSubview(profileImageView)
    setupInputContainerView()
    setupLoginRegisterButton()
    setupProfileImageView()
}
//MARK: - Constraints
func setupProfileImageView(){
    //need x, y, width , height
    profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.topAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
}
func setupInputContainerView(){
    // need x, y, width and height constraint
    inputContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    inputContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    inputContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
    inputContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true

    inputContainerView.addSubview(nameTextField)
    inputContainerView.addSubview(nameSeparatorView)
    inputContainerView.addSubview(emailTextField)
    inputContainerView.addSubview(emailSeparatorView)
    inputContainerView.addSubview(passwordTextField)

    // need x, y, width , height constraints
    nameTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    nameTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    nameTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3).isActive = true

    // need x, y, width, height constraints
    nameSeparatorView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    nameSeparatorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    nameSeparatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    nameSeparatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

    // need x, y, width , height constraints
    emailTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    emailTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    emailTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3).isActive = true

    // need x, y, width, height constraints
    emailSeparatorView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    emailSeparatorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    emailSeparatorView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    emailSeparatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

    passwordTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    passwordTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    passwordTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/3).isActive = true
}
func setupLoginRegisterButton(){
    // need x, y, width and height constraint
    loginRegisterButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    loginRegisterButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    loginRegisterButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    loginRegisterButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

//    loginRegisterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(registerTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

}
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
    get{
        return .lightContent
    }
}
//MARK: Actions
@objc func registerTapped(){
    print("Registered")
}
}
extension UIColor{
    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1.0)
   }
}
```

**Question:**

I would like to separate following type of view declarations into separate file so I can pass parameters to it and generate (get in return) the required UI component (e.g. View, Button, Textfield, line).

```
let inputContainerView: UIView = {
    var view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true

    return view
}()
```

I also want to separate the constraints to one separate file so I can call and apply any constraints just by passing required constraints as parameter. So following type of constraints will go into a separate external file. We can pass positioning constraints like we do in web CSS property (e.g. `margin: 4px 2px 0 4px` and may be a relative element *reference* as parameter also, so the constraints can be applied with reference to any other element, when needed.)

```
func setupProfileImageView(){
    //need x, y, width , height
    profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputContainerView.topAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
   profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
}
```

This way my code for the views will shirk to few number of lines i.e. 70% reduced when I separate these declarations and operations into separate swift file.

Comment: thats ok! but what is the issue in this?

Comment: In my question second part I asked about how to separate the UI components code to separate swift file and also constraints to be moved in separate external file. So the code gets optimized, manageable and less code is required to write for every View.

Comment: MuhammadHannan the question that @dahiya_boy is asking is, you seem to have posted all the required code and understand the mechanics. Why have you posted a stackoverflow question. What part of the task is not working, what error messages have you received etc? As it stands you have explained what you want to do, but not what issue you are having. Keeping in mind, stackoverflow isn't a freelancing website, nobody is going to write your code for you, we are only here to debug issues, errors etc.

Comment: @Simon nice clarification. Actually I get `view are in different hierarchy` error. I will post details if required.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think you wanted to categorise your single VC file code into different files so that it can be manageable easily.

First of know, keep in mind I do not know what your code is actually doing. I am just explaining **how to create extension file** and **how to use it.**

**Extension file** helps you to manage the single file code into multiple files. You can use variables & call the func by using `self`.

**Note :** You can not declare variables in extension file. If you try you got below error.

[image]

### **how to create extension file**

1. In your project create new file.

[image]

2. Select swift file.

[image]

3. Save it with format -> `<your_VC_Name>+<File_purpose>`

**your_VC_Name** is the VC for which you are creating extension.

**File_purpose** is the purpose or specification of creating extension. eg. for constraints funs I used `Constraints` and if i want extension for web services then i named it webservices.

Don't forget to add `+` in between.

Above description is just a naming convention so that every body can easily understand as it is standard format.

[image]

### **how to use extension :**

1. Use below code to make your file as extension file.

   ```
   import Foundation

   extension LoginController {

   }
   ```
2. Now cut your func from the `LoginController` and paste here in the extension file.

   ```
   extension LoginController {
      func myFunc() {
       }
   }
   ```
3. Simplly call your func like this

   ```
   self.myFunc()
   ```

**Note:** You can use any func by using `self` irrespective of where your func is written. But you can declare any variable in extension file.

Answer (score 1):

Muhammad! How far along are you with this?

There are multiple ways of achieving what I think you want to do, depending on how are you going to re-use the UI components and the constraints.

The first thing that comes to my mind is to define a convenience initializer to create an instance of the UI component class for a specific use case or input value type. (More info on convenience init [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)).

For example, you could have file with all the custom classes. For instance, a `GenericButton` class inherited from the `UIButton` class with a convenience init and setting the specific parameters you would like to, like this:

```
import UIKit

class GenericButton: UIButton {

    convenience init(color: UIColor, text: String) {
        self.init()
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.backgroundColor = color
        self.titleLabel?.text = text
    }
}

class GenericTextField: UITextField {

    convenience init(placeholder: String) {
        self.init() 
        self.placeholder = placeholder
    }
}
```

And then initialize them from wherever you're going to use them like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var loginButton: GenericButton!
    var inputText: GenericTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loginButton = GenericButton(color: .blue, text: "Hello")
        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)

        inputText = GenericTextField(placeholder: "Placeholder")
        self.view.addSubview(inputText)
    }
}
```

The concept of this separation with the views/UI components makes a lot of sense, but I'm not so sure about the constraints since you're going to relate one view with another in a very specific way, sometimes involving more that one view, you need to have a reference of each view involved in the same file in order to do so. It'll end up being super specific to your needs.

One way I can think of by following the idea above is, extending the classes in the file where you have all your custom UI components with a function to set up constraints. Something like this:

```
class GenericButton: UIButton {

    convenience init(color: UIColor, text: String) {
        self.init()

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.backgroundColor = color
        self.titleLabel?.text = text
    }
}

extension GenericButton {

    func setupConstraints(x: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor, y: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor, width: NSLayoutDimension, height: NSLayoutDimension) {
        self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: x).isActive = true
        self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: y, constant: 12).isActive = true
        self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: width).isActive = true
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    }
}
```

And call that function from wherever you initialized the component, like this:

```
loginButton = GenericButton(color: .blue, text: "Hello")
loginButton.setupConstraints(x: 10.0, y: 10.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
```

Let me know if you already found a different approach!

Comment: Have not tried the solution yet, so I appreciate your answer and will vote after doing the test.